# Set Maximum content-length Accepted

Tags: ruby-on-rails, security

Is there a way in Rails to specify the maximum allowed content-length so that requests that exceed this value are rejected immediately?

I have a login form on my application that is the only POST available to an unauthenticated user. This has been identified as a potential vulnerability to a slow POST DoS attack. One of the mitigations is to limit the allowed request size.

I cannot seem to find the knob to turn which will allow me to automatically reject the request if the content-length exceeds a particular value.

We're using the Puma web server if that affects the answer.

Comment: have you tried reading the request headers in your login controller?

Comment: I am sure that I could do that. I am trying to find something that would be a bit more canonical Rails.

Answer (score -1):

Puma has two parameters actually, the number of threads and the number of workers. If we slightly change the default **puma.rb**, it will look like that:

```
workers Integer(ENV['WORKERS_NUMBER'] || 1)
max_threads_count = Integer(ENV['RAILS_MAX_THREADS'] || 1)
min_threads_count = max_threads_count
threads min_threads_count, max_threads_count
```